# Calculate AIC of an AR process knowing the coefs and n?

Tags: time-series, aic, autoregressive

In a paper I'm reading, the authors determine the order of an AR process via AIC. Fine. But they do so from the AR coefficients and length of the process and *not* from the time series itself. The formula given is
$$aic_p = n \times  ln(\sigma) + 2.0 \times p$$

where $p$ is the order (lag), $n$ is the length of the time series and "$\sigma$ is calculated from the AR coefficients." Any insight into how this last part is actually done? Imagine I have three AR models I'm considering with coefficients as:

```r
ARmat <- matrix(c(-0.3694, 0, 0, -0.3443, -0.06798, 0, -0.3408, 
           -0.05006, -0.05204), 3, 3, byrow = TRUE)
row.names(ARmat) <- c("ar(1)", "ar(2)", "ar(3)")
ARmat
```

And $n=300$. Can I get the AIC for AR(1), AR(2), and AR(3)?

Comment: Can you give a link to the paper for reference?

Comment: Not at the moment. It's in review. This part of the paper is a bit hard to follow to say the least!

Comment: That does not make sense. For a fixed set of AR coefficients, there can be many different time series with diffferent values of $\sigma$. They may be phrasing things wrong.